# When to use forwardslash and when not to use forwardslash?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying out basic login using JSP and Servlets and don't understand how forwardslashes are used to indicate the path.

login.JSP is located in LoginApp/WebContent/login.jsp

LoginServlet.java is located in LoginApp/src/org/koushik/javabrains/LoginServlet.java

I have the following code in my login.jsp file -

```
 <form action="login" method="post">

 <br>User ID  input type="text" name="userId" />
 <br>Password <input type="password" name="password" />
 <br><input type="submit" />

 </form>
```

The corresponding servlet code is

```
  @WebServlet("/login")  // <-- forwardslash here
  public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet 
   {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
      {
         String userId, password;

         userId = request.getParameter("userId");
         password = request.getParameter("password");

                 // more code here
      }

    }
```

If we see the form action, there is no forwardslash before "login", whereas if we see the servlet annotation, there is a forwardslash before "login". Why this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
@WebServlet("/login")
```

The `/login` is a url pattern that is relative applications to the [contextPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29)

e.g. if your application had a context path of `webapp` then a request to

`http://localhost:8080/webapp/login` would load the `LoginServlet`

In your jsp the form action

Is relative to the jsp page *itself*, and **not** the contextPath.

However because your jsp is located in the webroot folder (the top level folder where your jsp's and WEB-INF folder live)

`http://localhost:8080/webapp/login.jsp`

then the `action="login"` attribute in the form

will resolve to the location

`http://localhost:8080/webapp/login`

when the form is submitted and will call the `LoginServlet`

If you move the jsp into a subfolder (e.g. folder1) then `action=login` will not call the login servlet

as the jsp will now be located at

`http://localhost:8080/webapp/subfolder/login.jsp` 
and so `action=login`

will now resolve to 
`http://localhost:8080/webapp/subfolder/login`

and the servlet will not be found (remember the login servlet is relative to the context root, thats what the / means in `@WebServlet("/login")`)

changing the form action to

```
<form action="../login" method="post">
```

would work.

To avoid having to work this out in webpage forms

most people will change the form action to look like this

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
```

So that where ever the jsp is located the el expression

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login`

will resolve to same location as the servlet defined with url pattern /login

see [What does this expression language ${pageContext.request.contextPath} exactly do in JSP EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850336/what-does-this-expression-language-pagecontext-request-contextpath-exactly-do) for more info an the el expression

Hope this helps

Comment: Cheers dude, im a bit tired so wasnt quite sure it made sense, glad it helped, i'll try and "tidy it up" tomorrow