# Eclipse jsp error in editor

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, syntax-error

I'm getting errors (on X lines) in a jsp file but it all seems to be right.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="GET"
X           action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/docreatetask">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td><input name="task" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><input name="description" type="textarea" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Deadline</td>
                <td><input name="description" type= /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
X                   <td><input name="Create new task" type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
```

```
**Error 1** javax.servlet.ServletException can not be resolved
**Error 2** javax.servlet.http can not be resolved
```

What could it be? Is it using ServletException or javax.servlet.http anywhere?

Comment: Is only this jsp showing error or if there are other they are also showing

Comment: Project works fine but the editor is showing that errors

Comment: @Joe I am asking if this particular jsp is showing error or all are.

Comment: if your project works fine it can be a small problem .Do one thing select all your jsp page copey all contents of jsp press del and paste again and save..But if all jsps showing problem then add servlet -api jar

Comment: I tried that and it works for a while, but afterwards the same error came up again. Finally I added servlet-api.jar in classpath. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first error (`java.servlet.http can not be resolved to a type`), You need to put `servlet-api.jar` file in the `classpath:

To do this follow the steps:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Click on build path -> Configure build path
3. In libraries tab -> click Add external jars
4. Select `servlet-api.jar` file

For your second error:(`javax.servlet.ServletException can not be resolved`):

1. Right Click on project
2. Select Properties tab
3. Select targeted runtime tab
4. Check the server you are using

Comment: It worked fine. But I can't understand where I'am using such classes. It was only html in it.

Comment: @Joe by using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in your code, you are using `HttpServletRequest` object which requires `servlet-api.jar` file. Have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5850406/1551233).

Comment: @Joe also there are some errors in your html code. You are defining `textarea` wrong way. And you have not specified `type` for `description` input.