# Css not working when I pass the error message from java servlet

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page which contains some fields. I need to validate those fields from server side (i.e,from java servlet class). I put all error messages in a map and I am forwarding the messages to the jsp page.

See my jsp page with css.

[image]

When I click on submit button the css is not working.

See this image

[image]

This is how I am forwaring my error messages to jsp page.

```
                if(errors.size()>0)
                        {
                         request.setAttribute("map",errors);
                         RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("admin/adduser.jsp");
                         rd.forward(request, response);

                       }
```

Please help me.

This css I added in head tag

This is my form code

```
Map<String,String> errors=null;
 %>
 <%
      if(request.getAttribute("map")!=null){
       errors=(Map<String,String>)request.getAttribute("map");
    }
    %>
    <body>
     <form action="../BrightSymphonyController" method="post">
      <%if(request.getParameter("name")== null ||"".equals(request.getParameter("name"))){ %>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="textbox2" maxlength=""/>
        <span style="color:red " class="error"><%=(errors!=null?(errors.get("name")!=null?errors.get("name"):""):"")%></span>
        <%} else{ %>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="textbox2" value="<%=request.getParameter("name")%>"/>
        <%} %>

        </form>
        </body>
```

I added only one field code.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: When I pass the error messages from servlet my jsp page css is not working. Please help me

Comment: add your css link code snippet. I think you've used relative path in link code like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` and that might causing the issue.

Comment: <link href="../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     This is my css

Comment: ok so instead of giving relative path in href add `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` and give absolute path with proper folder structure.

Comment: I added my css in head tag

Comment: I did not get what you said. My css file path is WebContent--->cssfolder-->stylesheet.css

Comment: change your link tag with `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Yes it is working @Parth. Can you please explain this line ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment I've found that you've used relative url to link css in jsp.

```
<link href="../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So, when you forward your error message to `adduser.jsp`, it might happen that your browser will not find that intended css because you've given relative path like `../css/yourfile.css`.

Instead use absolute url to your css using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` so no matter how you're accessing your page it'll always resolve to correct url path.

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also read about [${pageContext.request.contextPath}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5850406/2068790)