# @requestmapping and ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping, modelandview

Hi help me please with Spring RequestMapping. I have page like this:

```
<form action="/add_photo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                Photo: <input type="file" name="photo">
                <input type="submit" />
     </form>
```

and controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

    private Map<Long, byte[]> photos = new HashMap<>();


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String onIndex() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_photo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView onAddPhoto(@RequestParam MultipartFile photo) {
        if (photo.isEmpty()) {
            throw new PhotoErrorException();            
        }

        try {
            long id = System.currentTimeMillis();
            photos.put(id, photo.getBytes());

            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
            model.addObject("photo_id", id);
            model.setViewName("result");
            return model;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new PhotoErrorException();
        }
    }
}
```

method "onIndex" is working but onAddPhoto seems not and when I click button whith URL "/add_photo" it gives me 404 instead page "result"

Comment: What is the URL displayed in the address bar when displaying your form? What is the URL displayed in the address bar after you've submitted the form?

Comment: after submitting form it's displays "/add_photo"

Comment: And before submitting?

Comment: before "http://localhost:8080/photos/" and after "http://localhost:8080/add_photo"

Comment: So, if the full path for `@RequestMapping("/")` is `/photos/`, what should be the full url for `@RequestMapping(value = "/add_photo"`? Should it be `/add_photo`, or should it rather be `/photos/add_photo`? What do you think this `/photos`prefix is, and where does it come from?

Comment: /photos prefix is come from deploing .war file on Tomcat server. That's a name of the project.

Comment: So you need to add this prefix to every URL pointing to a resource of your application (as Suraj's answer explains).

Comment: should I add it only in jsp page or in jsp and controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pageContext in your jsp page as:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add_photo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
Photo: <input type="file" name="photo">
            <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

For more details: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850336/what-does-this-expression-language-pagecontext-request-contextpath-exactly-do)

Comment: it's just deleted message [before](https://github.com/mrRodman/hello-world/blob/master/photos/errors/123.PNG) and [after](https://github.com/mrRodman/hello-world/blob/master/photos/errors/1234.PNG)