# Jsp include not working: file not found, status 500

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have directory structure like this:

[image]

Trying to include `header.jsp` in `home.jsp` like this:

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: Irina
  Date: 31.03.20
  Time: 20:58
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/shared/header.jsp" />
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">Login</a>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/signup">Signup</a>

</body>
</html>
```

fails with `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/comediansapp/shared/header.jsp] not found` error. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the path relative to the current page.
Try:

```
<jsp:include page="shared/header.jsp"/>
```

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is the current contextPath of the app in your case is **comediansapp** so it will try to find a file on the path **/comediansapp/shared/header.jsp**

Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5850406/4325878

Complete example that I tried:

[image: Project]

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="shared/header.jsp" />
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login.jsp">Login</a>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/signup.jsp">Signup</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**shared/header.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<nav style="height:50px; background:red;">
    <strong> JSP!!! </strong>
</nav>
```

**Working Example:**
[image: Working Example]

Comment: Thank you. It started working after I put it out of shared into the same folder. Then I put it back into shared and it kept working. Not sure why. In your answer you provide structure for Eclipse, it seems. Similar enough, but I'd recommend checking out Idea + Maven ; ) Anyways I appreaciate your help and effort, hopefully your answer will help many other people too.