# how to access jsp file in Sub folder

Tags: jsp

i am making a OnlineBankingSystem Project
but am facing one problem..i am making a folder called Admin in this folder placed jsp file but i unable to access this files..below is structure using Eclipse

WebContent/Admin/File1.jsp,File2.jsp

http://localhost:8083/OnlineBanking/Admin/AdminSignup.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't clear based on my understanding ,I would try to give Solution.
I'm assuming that the issue persists in how you redirect page one to another.IF you Right Click-->Run File(JSP) it will surely run.

But when going from JSP to Another JSP you might face some issue.

--> WebContent/Admin/File1.jsp

---> WebContent/File2.jsp

Consider that if you are going :File2.jsp -->File1.jsp

Then the code should be in File2.jsp

```
  <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>  // Add this on Top of your JSP
  <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Admin/File1.jsp">Admin Page</a>
```

Refer--> [What does this expression language ${pageContext.request.contextPath} exactly do in JSP EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850336/what-does-this-expression-language-pagecontext-request-contextpath-exactly-do)

Comment: above solution is Correct......i  implemented in my project ..it's working..